# Need help building an app using the Salesforce Platform (Lightning App Builder / Force.com / anything else)

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

I'm kind of stuck... I'm not exactly sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

I'm trying to build a webapp with minimal coding. The webapp should display fields which can be saved into a database on the click of a button. Then when that database gets a new record, I want to send an email. Then I want to have admin page where I can see what other people have submitted.

I'd be grateful for any help. From what I'm seeing, what I'm trying to do is not possible (even with code), because the SalesForce platform is very tightly focused with CRM. If my assumptions are wrong, please correct me and point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Edit: Please comment. I need help on this ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that salesforce.com's roots hail back to being a pure CRM, but it has long since evolved into an entire PaaS (Platform-as-a-Service). Many things that used to require all kinds of coding can be done with simple point and click interfaces. What you're looking to do is entirely possible, can could probably be set up in an hour or less.

First, create the objects, fields, and tabs you want to expose to the public. Next, set up a Community, configure it to display the items from the first step, and then publish your community. At this point, anyone can go into the community and create/update records, depending on the configuration you set. Afterwards, you can use Process Builder to send those emails when certain conditions arise. Of course, since you're in Salesforce, you can simply log in, go to the tab, and view the records placed by other people, or you can even run reports, export the data, make charts based on the data, and more.

Comment: Is this using the Lightning App Builder? How do I create the object fields and tabs and then expose them to the public? Where do I create the community? Sorry, for all these questions. If you could point me to a good tutorial, that would be so so helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Jaime you'll want to read the [Salesforce Communities Implementation Guide (pdf)](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/13/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf), as it gives you the lowdown on how to work with communities. As for creating objects and fields, check out the Admin | Beginner courses on the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/), or you can read the [online help manual](https://help.salesforce.com/), but I'd recommend the Trailhead first; it's a guided tour of features.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into those guides. So are these guides are using salesforce's force.com platform right? Lighting App Builder is also not the right tool for the job right? It seems like that one is for sure directly tied to just CRM.

Comment: @Jaime No, you can build all sorts of apps in App Builder, but its primary purpose is internal, rather than external. For example, you could build an ERP app, or a CMS app, a drone-control app, or even a coffee-pot app. Again, salesforce.com is no longer a CRM, it's a Platform-as-a-Service that happens to have a lot of CRM features built in.

Comment: Gotcha. So the reason the Lighting App Builder won't work is because it's intended to be used internally. Which is why the app I'm trying to build has to be done using force.com's interface right? Where I'll build objects, fields, tabs, and the community.

Comment: @Jaime Yes, you'll build the fields and objects in Setup (or the Schema Builder), then you can create your Community. Go ahead and give the docs a read, and if you come across specific questions, please feel free to ask; that's what we're here for!

Comment: Thank you so much!! :D You've answered my biggest questions. I'm gonna forth and start creating. I'll hit you up if I run into any issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49390/discussion-between-jaime-and-sfdcfox).